# C# ToolStripControlHost Resize doesn't affect toolstrip size

Tags: c#, winforms

i added ToolStripControlHost with inner control to ToolStrip. When the inner control rezise the toolstrip doesn't grow although AutoSize is true for both  toolstrip and ToolStripControlHost . i would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try changing Anchor property ?

Comment: can you set a font size for your tooltip?

Comment: how to set anchor property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ToolStripSeparator toolStripSeparator = new ToolStripSeparator()
            {
                Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Left,
                Overflow = ToolStripItemOverflow.Never,
                BackColor = Color.White
            };
            toolStrip1.Items.Add(toolStripSeparator);

            ToolStripControlHost toolStripControl = new ToolStripControlHost(mainFiltersControl)
            {
                Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Left,
                Overflow = ToolStripIte`enter code here`mOverflow.Always,
                BackColor = Color.White,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };
            toolStrip1.Items.Add(toolStripControl);


            ToolStripButton toolStripButton = new ToolStripButton(Messages.AdditionalFiltersTitle)
            {
                Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Right,
                Overflow = ToolStripItemOverflow.Never,
                ToolTipText = Messages.AdditionalFiltersTooltipDisabled,
                BackCol`enter code here`or = Color.White
            };
            toolStripButton.Click += additionalFiltersButton_Click;

            toolStrip1.Items.Add(toolStripButton);
```

Comment: the problem is that mainFiltersControl grows in runtime but toolstrip remain the same size

Answer (score 0):

You should false the Autosize,And then set height and width of Toolstrip and Toolstripcontrol
For Eg:

```
    this.toolStrip1.AutoSize = false;
    this.toolStripButton1.AutoSize = false;
    this.toolStripButton2.AutoSize = false;
    this.toolStripButton3.AutoSize = false;
    this.toolStripButton1.Height = 20;
    this.toolStripButton2.Height = 40;
    this.toolStripButton3.Height = 60;
    this.toolStrip1.Height = 65;
```

like this...

Comment: But the inner control grows on run time by user selections